# Count total of last 28 cells until 3 consecutive 0's then restart

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table in an Excel spreadsheet that is adding up hours worked. I need to be able to add up the last 28 cells which have data in them to get a total for the month. However if there are 3 consecutive 0's (days off) I need the formula to reset counting. I have the formula for row B. Just after Row C. Table below.
Hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Do you want us to give you a formula for Column ``B`` also, or do you already have that?  If you already have a formula, you should tell us. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: So for less than 28 days, you want the cumulative.  After 28 days, you want a rolling cumulative of the last 28 days?  (and start over after three consecutive 0s.)

Comment: That's correct @fixer1234

Comment: Hey @fixer1234 I'm still stuck with this formula are you able to help out? Thanks

Comment: Your question has some complexity.  Don't worry about an elegant solution.  Add additional helper columns to figure out the components, like number of days in the run and where that puts the starting cell for the aggregation.  Then use that to generate your totals.  Once you have something working, you can look at simplifying it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could make this work, but all of them need some kind of count of days somewhere.

So lets make things easy, and add one in col D.

```
=IFERROR(IF(B1=3,1,IF(D1>27,1,D1+1)),1)
```

In col C:

```
=IFERROR(IF(D2=1,A2,A2+E1),A2)
```

Comment: Thanks @SirAdelaide but I need a rolling cumulative of the last 28 days and at any stage I have 3 0's then it needs to reset and start counting from that point again.

Comment: the if statement should do that: it resets to A (0) if col B has a 3 in it, otherwise continues adding A to the most recent value in C. The only thing this doesn't do is count the 28 days. Do you need that too?

Comment: Yes please @SirAdelaide. In col C it has to count the last 28 days in a rolling cumulative total. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Hey @sirAdelaide Sorry unless I'm doing something wrong I don't think it's working. I've added the two formulas to col C and D and have the following results. Col C is 0's all the way down and col D is working as it will put a 1 if there are three days off in a row.

Comment: there were a few mistakes - I wrote the formulae from my head. I've just tested them in Excel and should work now.

Comment: Hey @sirAdelaide I got the days counting but unfortunately it needs to be a rolling 28 days not count 28 days and at the end of those 28 days start again. Every day a new entry is made and it needs to count back 28 days from each entry.

Comment: I had an offset formula which seemed to work counting the rolling 28days (if i added 27 blank cells above col A) =IF(b3>=3,0,SUM(OFFSET(a2,0,0,-28,1))) so if would reset the counting if three days off were reached. However the next row down after the three days off it would just keep counting again rather than starting again.